# ¿Cómo poner el nombre de tabla como variable en una consulta SQL en SQLITE3? - Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite3

En esta ocasión quiero preguntar acerca de cómo pasar una variable a una consulta SQL.
La operación que pretendo realizar es que a través de un GUI pueda seleccionar el nombre de la tabla existente en un archivo .DB y esta sea asignada a una variable, dicha variable se debe incluir a la consulta SQL que permita realizar modificaciones en la tabla.

La finalidad de dicha rutina es para hacer una consulta genérica en la cual no deba hacer múltiples rutinas para las múltiples tablas existentes sino que con una sola rutina pueda hacer el mismo proceso para cualquier tabla seleccionada.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Tengo el siguiente código pero no he podido solucionar el problema:

Métodos del GUI:

```
def frame_dbm(self): # NNo olvidar dar  self.sentinel el valor  False !!!!! Generar un FRame BASE para integrar el Label Frame
    
    self.LF2=LabelFrame(self.left_frame,bg="white", text="System's Data")
    self.LF2.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=2,pady=10)
    Label(self.LF2,text="Check the table to display the information",bg="white").grid(pady=5, padx=2,row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)
    array=self.GI.view_table_log()
    self.n=StringVar()
    self.list1=ttk.Combobox(self.LF2,textvariable=self.n,values=array,state="readonly")
    self.list1.grid(pady=10, padx=2,row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
    self.list1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',self.list1_changed)


def list1_changed(self,event):
        value=self.list1.get() #Este valor representa la tabla dentro el archivo.DB
        #Aquí va la sentencia SQL que extrae de la tabla asignada el nombre de las columnas - Usar la función QUERY de DB_Manager.
        self.GI.view(value)
        #Aquí va la rutina de TKTREEVIEW que desplega la tabla resultante.
        self.table=ttk.Treeview(self.ppal_frame)
        print(value)
```

Función que busca los nombres dentro del Archivo .DB

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import os

class Gen_info:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        folder=os.getcwd()
        db_folder=(folder+os.sep+"Data_Bases"+os.sep)
        self.db_name=(db_folder+'database.db')
        print(self.db_name)

        self.view_table_log()

    def sql_password(self,esp1,esp2):
            query='SELECT * FROM Users_guide WHERE user=? AND password=?'
            parameters=(esp1,esp2)
            self.run_query(query,parameters)
            if self.result.fetchall():
                return True
            else:
                return False
    
    def validation(self,data1,data2):
        return len(data1)!=0 and len(data2)!=0

    
    def run_query(self,query,parameters=()):
        with sqlite.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            self.cursor=conn.cursor()
            self.result=self.cursor.execute(query,parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return self.result

    def view_table_log(self):
        query='SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" ORDER BY name'
        self.run_query(query)
        array=[item[0]for item in self.cursor.fetchall()]
        return array

    def view(self,value):#Pasar el parámetro Value desde el SCRIPT PPAL.
        query="""SELECT value.id AS value_id, value.name AS value
        FROM value ORDER BY value ASC"""
        self.run_query(query)
        A1=self.cursor.description()
        print(A1)
```

Comment: Este tipo de rutinas no se recomiendan por ser un indicador de problemas de diseño.  Ya sea que tengas tablas con la misma estructura o que estés haciendo consultas que regresen datos innecesarios. Además de que se abre la posibilidad de inyección de SQL al tener ese tipo de consultas dinámicas.

Comment: @LuisCazares, Me puedes indicar qué opciones puedo tener, lo menciono debido a que pretendo ver los datos contenidos en las diferentes tablas mediante el Widget Treeview, intento hacerlo con consultas dinámicas con la finalidad de no escribir ad hoc para cada tabla. Lo anterior lo menciono porque estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en la cual uso un archivo .DB como proveedor de información, la finalidad de poder consultar las tablas es modificar los datos en caso tal de errores en los datos contenidos.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que captures la variable, por ejemplo en `var` y `ver`, y el nombre de la tabla `table_name` puedes pasarla directamente a tu query de esta manera:

```
query = f"""select * from {table_name} where val1='{var}' or val2='{ver}'"""
```

para comprobar, puedes correr este ejemplo:

```
>>> var = 'uno'
>>> ver = 'dos'
>>> table_name= 'my_table'
>>> query = f"""select * from {table_name} where val1='{var}' or val2='{ver}'"""
>>> query
"select * from my_table where val1='uno' or val2='dos'"
```

Comment: de la sentencia anterior que me indicas, cómo la puedo adaptar para que la variable capturada (Value) sea aplicada al nombre de la tabla " FROM Value", mi idea es poder volver genérica la sentencia SQL para poderla aplicar a cualquier tabla dentro del archivo .DB

Comment: Ah, entiendo. Te sirve poniendo la etiqueta {} en ves del texto tabel? Capturas el archivo DB, guardas el nombre en dbbame y la pasas a query con el {query} en vez de ‘tabel’

Comment: @JonásArbeláezTorres cuando hiciste el comentario estaba medio dormido, ahora ya he corregido la respuesta para indicar como usar la variable como nombre de tabla. Avisame si eso te sirve

Comment: Encontré una manera, sería bueno que me des tú punto de vista.

Comment: @JonásArbeláezTorres, si, la acabo de ver. Yo suelo mandar mis querys a traves de ```pandas``` con ```pandas.read_sql(query, conn)```, asi solo defino la conexion ```conn``` y me ahorro los ```cursor```. Otro comentario que te hago es que de esta forma, me han fallado los querys que no vienen con triple comilla, pero si funcionan bien cuando haces por ejemplo ```"select * from column column1 where campo='{}' ".format(variable)```, solo que por preferencia personal, prefiero usar los ```f-string``` (```f"select * from column column1 where campo='{variable}'"```) pq los considero mas legibles.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la siguiente manera de realizar el proceso solicitado en la pregunta.

La variable Value viene desde otra rutina que toma el valor deseado.

La forma es la siguiente: **query='SELECT * FROM {}'.format(value)**

```
def run_query(self,query,parameters=()):
    with sqlite.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        self.cursor=conn.cursor()
        self.result=self.cursor.execute(query,parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return self.result


def view(self,value):#Pasar el parámetro Value desde el SCRIPT PPAL.
    query='SELECT * FROM {}'.format(value)
    print(query)
    self.run_query(query)
    names=[x[0] for x in self.result.description]
    print(names)
```

Comment: Hola Jonas, recuerda que puedes seleccionar tu respuesta como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.